# How to set the background image according to screen size?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, screen-size

I want to set an image according to screen size. I've been going through many codes on it but I've not found a working solution yet. I'm using Xcode 5.1.1 and Iphone Retina 4inch. Whenever I add my background image, it becomes huge and goes out of screen size. Kindly help me.

Comment: You should set the size of UIImageView according to your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code from Anbu's answer to get the screen height and set the image to aspectFit to avoid it from getting huge and out of bounds:

```
yourImageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
yourImageview.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your view is directly added to a `UIViewController` you should use the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` ([doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews)) method to do the resize. Something like this:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = self.bounds;
}
```